# Piping timechart into streamstats

Tags: logging, charts, frequency, splunk

We have splunk index for certain events.  Events are categorized by event type.

I need to find fixed size (let say, 5 min) windows where frequency (events per second) of any events drops/rises more than a preset percentage (let say, 50%) as compared to a preceding window.

I, unsuccessfully, tried something like this:

```
 index=index_of_events | eval cnt=1 | timechart span=20s limit=40 per_second(cnt) as ev  by ev_type useother=f usenull=f |
 streamstats window=40 global=false first(ev) as start last(ev) as end by ev_type | 
 eval diff=abs(start-end) | eval max_val=max(start, end) | 
 where diff > 0 AND max > 0 | eval prc=100*diff/max_val | where prc > 50
```

Is it approach doable? Can I pipe `timechart` directly to `streamstats` or do I need something like `untable` between them?

Is there a better way to accomplish such task?

If possible I would also like to exclude low frequency events (do not care if `2/sec` becomes `1/sec`).

Answer (score 0):

Often timechart is best left until last, try stats instead

(remove //comments)

```
search ...
// group by type
| stats count by type
// establish a 'normal'
| streamstats window=5 global=f median(count) as floating_median by type
// calculate delta
| eval diff = count-floating_median
| eval diff_percent = diff/floating_median
// find outliers
| eventstats max(diff_percent) as diff_percent_max by type
| where diff_percent_max > 0.5
// visualise
| timechart sum(count) as count by type
```